# Hide superuser from User's list

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I want to hide superuser's (admin role) from the user's list.

Currently, any user can find a root user with the search. I also have a view "list of members" where root appears. I would like to find a solution ...

I tried the "User One" module but nothing changes. I work on Drupal 8.

Thanks,
Nemtecl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In drupal 8 all lists are views. So if you want to hide the user with the id 1, you have to edit the view and set a filter.

Go to URL/admin/structure/views and choose the correct view and click on edit.

Now add a filter criteria and choose "User Id" and set the filter to User id NOT equals 1

Comment: Thanks! It worked for my "list of members". But if I search "root" on the site, the results are all content created by root

Comment: What are you expecting? The search is for content and the author is an indexed field. You can configure the default search page here: URL/admin/config/search/pages

/search/node is for content
/search/user ist for users

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a view of users and in **FILTER CRITERIA** add a filter for (Roles User Roles that a user belongs to.) and add a Operator **Is none of** and select the role from Options.[image]